# What's the license of videos created with Haiper AI?

Tags: text-to-video, haiper

I am creating some videos via [Haiper](https://haiper.ai/). What's the license of videos created with Haiper AI? E.g., can I make commercial use of it?

Comment: I am not sure if asking for a tool's license is considered asking for a legal matter, [which is off-topic](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/28). _**Questions about specific legal matters.** These questions are off-topic on Gen AI. While users generally contribute answers in good faith, the answers are not legal advice, and contributors here are not your lawyer. Consider [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour) instead._ Don't get me wrong. I would also love to know the answer to your question, but this is what we agreed to. Maybe it can be changed in the future. Maybe not.